# PhantomJS and OpenShift, impossible to make work?

Tags: linux, selenium, phantomjs, openshift, redhat

Lately I have been messing around with OpenShift and have had some problems with my project. I have a normal Python 2.7 cartridge installed and want to use Selenium with PhantomJS but any binaries of PhantomJS I have found didnt work (Ghostdriver wouldn't work). So I installed RHEL 7 and compiled it myself, which worked perfectly on my machine but once uploaded it failed to execute.

I think this was because of missing libraries so I copied the necessary libraries and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where I put them. But now I've gotten a new error:

```
 [...]/phantomjs: relocation error: [...]/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I use Phantomjs by itself (as well as casperjs) on OPENSHIFT.  It works fine.  Setting up working directory paths can be tricky but that's not open shifts fault.

Comment: @fatfantasma Could you please explain how you got PhantomJS running on OpenShift or give a link? since I still haven't found a solution for this problem. Thanks

Comment: I uploaded the phantomjs executable to the DATA directory in my openshift app.  My app is python based. I just call phantomjs with my desired script using python.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled the version 1.9.8 on CentOS 6.6 x86_64 with a patch to make GhostDriver play nice with OpenShift. If you think it may help, you can find the binary [here](https://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/phantomjs-with-ghostdriver-on-openshift/).